# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize

Tags: java, android, cordova

I was working away on my cordova plugin doing some refactoring and I started to get this crash on startup:

```
--------- beginning of crash
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime: Process: xyz.meris.app, PID: 4693
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xyz.meris.app/xyz.meris.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3162)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1993)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7266)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:171)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.startupPlugins(PluginManager.java:97)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:86)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.init(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:117)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:149)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:224)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at xyz.meris.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7353)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7344)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3142)
12-12 21:42:29.791  4693  4693 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more
12-12 21:42:29.826  4693  4693 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 4693 SIG: 9
```

I hunted around and found some similar questions:

- [android onActivityResult: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146591/android-onactivityresult-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-object-refe)
- [Class Not Found Exception using custom cordova plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343459/class-not-found-exception-using-custom-cordova-plugin)

But the solutions did not work for me...

Answer (score 1):

I got some clues from the other questions and because I was refactoring I had been working with the `plugin.xml` file.

I noticed that I had this difference from other `plugin.xml` files:

```xml
      <feature name="CDVProcessLog">
        <param name="android-package" value="xyz.meris.processlog.CDVProcessLog" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
      </feature>
      <feature name="ProcessLog">
        <param name="android-package" value="xyz.meris.processlog.ProcessLog" />
+       <param name="onload" value="true" />
      </feature>
```

Because I copied the `<feature>` tag and just filled it in I had copied the `onload` parameter.  Once I removed the duplicate `onload` parameter the crash stopped happening.

**EDIT:**
erp.  Turns out I had another error that was causing this issue.

Removing the `onload` param lazy loaded `ProcessLog`.  So I would get a null pointer error later.

My real problem was that my `.js` file did not get updated with my `CordovaPlugin` class name.  I had changed it from `ProcessLog`to `CDVProcessLog`.  `ProcessLog` now had the specifics for processing the log and `CDVProcessLog` had mostly cordova glue to call my methods in `ProcessLog`.

My `.js` file needed to change:

```js
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
-    exec(resolve, reject, 'ProcessLog', func, [...args]);
+    exec(resolve, reject, 'CDVProcessLog', func, [...args]);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in an Ionic application. The problem was caused by missing Java packages in `platforms/android/app/src/main/java` of some plugins that were defined in `config.xml`. Usually the reason for that is adding/removing cordova plugins manually.

To solve the problem, see a list of all `<feature>` tags in your `config.xml` file and make sure the packages (folder & files) defined in its `name` attribute present in `platforms/android/app/src/main/java`.

```
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<!-- etc. -->
```

To make search easier, look for the `ClassNotFoundException` in Android app's log files.

```
W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils
```